# How do I know when SCCM is done installing software packages after imaging?

Tags: sccm, imaging, software

We are preparing 3000 computers for deployment in a short amount of time.
We do this every year.  We had a last minute change and we are turning them on one by one to update them and while doing so I'm noticing about 10% of the workstations don't have all of the software packages that were supposed to install after imaging.  I assume this would be user error for not leaving the machine on long enough to "let the magic happen".  However we are blindly assuming after 24 hours of on-ness it is done.  I don't like uncertainty.

The computers are in a collection and the software is applied to the collection.  The workstations pick this up after the image is done automatically.

Is there a quick visual thing that can be configured like a background change to let a tech know when all of the software packages have installed after the computer has imaged?  Something that doesn't require running a report or logging into each workstation?